# Posting URL id to a flask blueprint endpoint

Tags: javascript, python, flask, post

Im using flask with Blueprints. I am trying to pass an ID from the url with a post request, but i dont understand the behaviour here:

i am on page localhost/2/updatestrat

This will post to /add_indicator

```
let indi_data = await postJsonGetData(data, "/add_indicator");
```

```
async function postJsonGetData(data, endpoint, method = "POST") {
  const options = {
    method: method,
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(data),
  };
  let response = await fetch(endpoint, options);

  if (!response.ok) {
    throw new Error("Request failed");
  }

  const responseData = await response.json();
  return responseData;
}
```

This will post to /2/load_conditions

```
  const { sell_conds, buy_conds } = await getJson("load_conditions");
```

```
async function getJson(endpoint) {
  const options = {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
  };
  let response = await fetch(endpoint, options);

  if (!response.ok) {
    throw new Error("Request failed");
  }

  const responseData = await response.json();
  console.log(responseData, "DDDDDDDD");
  return responseData;
}
```

How come that getJson will include the id of the page in the endpoint and postJsonGetData dont?

I can easily get the data from getJson like this

```
@bp.route('/<int:id>/load_conditions', methods=['POST'])
def load_conditions(id):
```

but when i try to do the same with "/add_indicator"

```
@bp.route('/<int:strategy_id>/add_indicator', methods=('POST',))
@login_required
def add_indicator(strategy_id):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print(strategy_id)
```

i get this error:
POST http://127.0.0.1:5000/add_indicator 404 (NOT FOUND)

so clearly it is not posting to the correct endpoint.

Comment: `http://127.0.0.1:5000/add_indicator `, it true 404 not found. Your true url is `/<int:strategy_id>/add_indicator` but you send a request dont have strategy_id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.
Instead of:

```
let indi_data = await postJsonGetData(data, "/add_indicator");
```

i should do:

```
let indi_data = await postJsonGetData(data, "add_indicator");
```